# Get default MediaStore file extension for video capture

Tags: java, android

I have a video capture from MediaStore with Intent.

```
           String videoFileName = String.valueOf(java.util.UUID.randomUUID());
           String fileExtension = "." + "mp4";
           String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();

           String videoFilePath = root + File.separator + videoFileName + fileExtension;

           File videoFile = new File(videoFilePath);

           String myCurrentVideoPath = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();

           Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
           if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
               if (videoFile != null) {
                   takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
                   startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
               }
           }
           ...
```

This is done in an `onClick` method. **Is it possible to take the defaut video file extension** for MediaStore and to assign it instead my `String fileExtension = "." + "mp4";`. I want to do this, because some cheep devices are recording only `.3gp`. Cheers to all stackoverflowers.